# How can I view an app in development from a remote computer?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, port, amazon-web-services

I have a domain [I'll call it `mydomain.com`] configured for a Lightsail instance. This Lightsail instance comes with NodeJS preinstalled, packaged by Bitnami, which makes some changes to a standard Apache2 install.

I am using Cloud9 to develop a ReactJS app on Lightsail, and I'd like to be able to view the changes without the tedious build and deploy steps. Is there a way for me to see the app from a remote machine (ie, my personal desktop) at `mydomain.com:3000`?

The instance is running:

- Debian GNU/Linux
- Node 16.18.1
- Apache 2.4

Edit:
The bot says I'm not clear.

I don't know how to configure this. I have successfully pointed the domain at the server, and ports 80 and 443 work with the domain OR the public IP for files in the htdocs folder.

It is my understanding that the Bitnami packaged server uses `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` instead of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, and that the Virtual Host configuration is at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/00_status-vhost.conf`. Finally, Bitnami has a file at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`, which holds similar information to vhosts. I've been playing with these configurations based on [this Bitnami page](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-port/)

**Pre-packaged configuration:**

- ports file has `Listen 80`
- vhosts has

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName status.localhost
  <Location /server-status>
    Require local
    SetHandler server-status
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

- bitnami conf has

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>
```

*Results*

- `mydomain.com` loads the contents of htdocs
- `ipaddress` loads the contents of htdocs
- `mydomain.com:3000` times out
- `ipaddress:3000` loads the running ReactJS app.
- Linux command `sudo netstat -ltnp` returns a tcp `0.0.0.0:3000`, a tcp6 for `:::80`, and a tcp6 :::8080`

**Adjustments I made**

- Add a line `Listen 3000` to the ports file
- Add the following to the vhosts file: `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:3000 _default_:3000>`
- Add the following to the bitnami conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:3000>
  ServerName *.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/subfolder"
</VirtualHost>
```

*Results*

- `mydomain.com` gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- `ipaddress` gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- `mydomain.com:3000` gives ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
- `ipaddress:3000` loads the ReactJS app.
- Linux command `sudo netstat -ltnp` returns a tcp `0.0.0.0:3000` and a tcp6 for `:::8080`

What do I need to configure? What did I configure wrong? And with what information?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not very familiar Lightsail, but did you allow port 3000 on the Security Group you applied to the load balancer or Elastic IP?

Comment: I'm also new to lightsail, so I could be wrong, but Lightsail while billed with the rest of AWS, kind of sits apart, from what I can see? setting up a Lightsail instance doesn't use anything in Route 53,  IAM, EC2, or anywhere. Even if you point a domain at it. it's entirely self contained. It has it's own key setup, firewall and domain assignment. 

So I do have port 3000 open on the instance's firewall, but there's nothing to configure anywhere else.